# common field for various Info-path forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, custom-form

I want to design 6 info-path forms and publish them in SharePoint online. Each form has some common field(basically drop downs) that has predefined data, we called it master fields. The requirement is that all of these field will be populated from a single table/list into each form and forms will saved in their respective form library.

any suggestion, how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You create your lists in Sharepoint Online with all the necessary fields and values. In your InfoPath form, you make a data connection to pull this information in. You can then bind that to a drop down field.

It is pretty straight forward to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into template parts - basically, you can create a template part with these controls (using a SharePoint list for the data source for the drop downs, as suggested in Eric Alexander's reply) and add the template part as a custom control in InfoPath designer. Adding the template part to any form you work on will give you the same layout / controls / data source in all your forms.